# garbage collection concurrent

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection

Why simple mark and sweep algorithm can't be done concurrently.

I have read that we need CMS(concurrent mark and sweep algorithm) for concurrent garbage collection that is more complex than simple mark and sweep algorithm but what is the problem with the simple one that we need CMS?

Comment: We can't explain that in a few paragraphs, so **your question is too broad**. You should read an entire book, like the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)

Comment: a brief reason for the problem of simple mark and sweep would be very helpful.

Comment: That requires several chapters so is too long to fit here. You'll first need to define what *exactly* concurrent garbage collection means (how do the mutator threads are running, are allocating, when is GC happening, do the mutators runs in parallel with the collectors threads, how do you do synchronization, write barriers, etc..)

Comment: Search the web for "multi-threaded garbage collection". But you really should read several books and lots of conference papers on GC, e.g. [ISMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Symposium_on_Memory_Management) proceedings. I strongly recommend reading the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) before. It probably is available in your university's library

Comment: http://www.pllab.riec.tohoku.ac.jp/papers/icfp2016UenoOhori-preprint.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest reason is that marker can miss some reachable objects if the path to an object changes. Consider following program and scenario:

```
a = new Object();
b = new Object();
b.c = new Object();
// gc process marks a, nothing reachable from a
a.c = b.c;
b.c = null;
// gc process marks b, nothing reachable from b
// marking phase completes, a.c is not marked
// gc sweeps a.c
print a.c; // safety violation
```